# Methods to migrate SQL Database (mdf) to SQL Compact Edition (sdf)

Tags: sql-server-2005, migration, sql-server-ce

I have 4 SQL Server 2005 db's that I want to move to SQL CE.  I know I cannot keep the SProcs,Views, and Functions(*[Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx)*) but I would like to keep everything else.

I have tried this app, ***[SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition Database Copy](http://www.johnnycantcode.com/page/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database-Copy.aspx)*** but it errors out on me.  I have the source and am looking into it but I thought I'd check and make sure I wasn't over complicating the solution to my ACTUAL goal.

Is there a simple, can be one shot, way of converting standard SQL `.mdf` to SQL CE `.sdf`?

Right now my best idea is to set up Replication to the SQL CE from the SQL 2005 Standard.

Answer (score 4):

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html

Comment: This one works with large DBs too (unlike others I've tried). Make sure you create a new SDF that is big enough though (using parameters in connection string).

Comment: The parameters Danny mention are: Max Database Size=4091

Answer (score 3):

1.Use [SQL Server to SQL Server Compact Edition Database Copy](http://www.johnnycantcode.com/page/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database-Copy.aspx) with sqlcompact 3.1 or 3.0 not sql compact 3.5
You can use a virtual machine like sun virtual box, install sql compact 3 or 3.1 on it, and convert your database inside it

2.You can convert to sql compact manually

Comment: It is supposed to work with 3.5, but it doesn't support the SPs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SDFViewer utility:

go Tools Menu > From SQL Server

Enough said....

Comment: +1 Seems to work (still running), SDFViewer is a commercial 3rd party tool.

Answer (score -1):

What if you scripted the objects from 2005 and ran the script in CE? That'd give you the structure of the DB, then you could select/insert?

I haven't tried this, but what about SQL's DB export/import tools in management studio?

Comment: Most of the script objects from SSMS don't run in SQL CE due to their use of things like sys tables.  You can't use the tools in SSMS either.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio Import/Export Tool does not seem to support CE. (At least not in 2008 R2.)