# How do i add an App_Data folder in window application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

How do i add an App_Data in my window application. Actaully i am facing an issue like

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Demo\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with
>   the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is
>   located on UNC share.

For this error i got an article saying that keep .mdf file in App_Data folder if we give path as `AttachDbFilename = | DataDirectory | / Database.mdf;` (as of now i am giving same path)  in connection string. so i need an App_Data folder in window application if not how to solve this error.

my connection string as fallows:

```
<add name="BCT" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SQL2005_652242_bct_data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: How to solve this issue Help me out from this @Hassanation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your connection string. i.e If you want to keep **DataDirectory** in your connection string then copy your mdf file in **bin\Debug** folder. This will work for sure. Try it.

Comment: When i build the project automatically .mdf is placed in bin\debug folder. @paresh Jadhav

Comment: You will not have problem connecting database and no need to change the connection string. It must be working??

Comment: I had been tried with your answere but it doesn't worked out for me. I am getting same error as before,no change in an error @paresh Jadhav

Comment: Try AppDomain.SetData to set your DataDirectory path. It must work. Check this URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632416/c-sharp-windows-form-application-with-database-not-running-on-clients-system

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder with the name `App_Data`. This folder is a normal folder that VS use to place data files.

Comment: I have tried your answer doesn't worked out for me is possible to get App_Data to be placed in window application. I Need in-built app_data but not creating manually for window application is it possible ? @Richard Dias

Comment: You already have the file `SQL2005_652242_bct_data.mdf`? If you already have the `.mdf` file, you must put him into `App_Data` folder and go to properties of file, pressing `Alt+Enter`, and set the property `copy local = true`. this will make your file be added to output folder inside the `App_Data` folder.

Comment: After pressing Alt+enter where should i set the property copylocal=true. ?? is it in  app.config  ?? @Richard Dias

Comment: No, not in `app.config`. With VS opened, select the file `SQL2005_652242_bct_data.mdf` and press `Alt+Enter`, so a tab named properties will appear, right? One of the properties of the file is `Copy local` and default value is `false`, you have to set to `true`. This will copy your `.mdf` file to output folder.